# cast Table<T> to something

Tags: c#, linq

I have a datacontext, and it has Authors table.

```
public partial Author:IProductTag{}
```

I want to cast `Table<Authors>` object to `Table<IProductTag>`, but that appears to be impossible. I am trying to do that because I want my method to be able to work with different tables which come as input parameters. To be more specific, I need to execute OrderBy and Select methods of the table. I have few other tables, entities of which implement IProductTag . Also, I tried to write a function like:

```
public static void MyF<t>(){ 
Table<t> t0 = (Table<t>)DataContext.GetMyTableUsingReflection(); 
}
```

But it fails at compile-time. And if I cast the table to something like ITable or IQueriable, then the OrderBy and Select functions simply don't work. So how do you deal with it?

Comment: Does `Authors` implement `IProductTag`? If not, is it a partial class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you want to make your method generic - so instead of

```
void DoSomethingWithTable(Table<IProductTag> table)
```

you should have

```
void DoSomethingWithTable<T>(Table<T> table) where T : class, IProductTag
```

That should work fine, assuming you only need to read entities (and apply query operators etc). If that *doesn't* work for you, please give more details about what your method needs to do.

(You say that your attempt to use reflection failed, but you haven't said in what *way* it failed. Could you give more details?)

Comment: void DoSomethingWithTable<T>(Table<T> table) where T : IProductTag doesn't work, I get: Error 4 The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'System.Data.Linq.Table<TEntity>'

Comment: I can get the Authors table using reflection, but I can't cast it to Table<IProductTag> .

Comment: Indeed! Had to specify "class" keyword.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what a `ProductTag` is so I've used different types to show my solution to this problem. Yes there doesn't seem to be a way to get a `Table<T>`, but you can get `IQueryable<T>` which works just as well (at least for my situation).

I have a simple analytics database, where each website has its own table containing both generic and specific items. I wanted to use an interface for the shared data.

```
public interface ISession 
{
    public DateTime CreateDt {get; set; }
    public string HostAddress {get; set; }
    public int SessionDuration {get; set; }
}

public static IQueryable<ISession> GetQueryableTable(MyDataContext db, string site)
{
     Type itemType;

     switch (item) 
     {
        case "stackoverflow.com":
            itemType = typeof(Analytics_StackOverflow);
            break;

        case "serverfault.com":
            itemType = typeof(Analytics_ServerFault);
            break;

        default: throw Exception();
     }

     return db.GetTable(itemType).Cast<ISession>();
}
```

You can then do a query like this :

```
  var table = GetQueryableTable(db, "stackoverflow.com");
  var mySessions = table.Where(s => s.HostAddress == MY_IP);
```

To create a new row you can use reflection :

```
  var rowType = typeof(Analytics_ServerFault); 
  var newRow =  (ISession) rowType.GetConstructor(new Type[0]).Invoke(new object[0]);
```

(I have a function to get GetRowType - which is not shown here).

Then to insert into the table I have a separate helper function:

```
 public static void Insert(MyDataContext db, ISession item) 
 {
     // GetTable is defined by Linq2Sql
     db.GetTable(GetRowType(domain)).InsertOnSubmit(item);
 }
```